# Spring get time to next cron schedule

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have implemented a class in spring boot with @scheduled as follows

```
@component
public class RunSchedule{
  @scheduled(cron="* * * 10 *")
     public void execute(){
        do something....
     }
}
```

I would like to be able to get the time to the next execution of the current method from within the code is this something that is possible?

Comment: there is no direct way. You need to use some library like quartz (org.quartz.CronExpression) to convert your cron expression to java Date and then compare it with your current time and get the next execution time